# Add migration issue with a nonexistent table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

When I generate a migration, it fails to reckon that I don't have a certain table (Reports) in the DB, so the generated migration is empty. Nonetheless, I have all the code in place for the generation to run smoothly.

This code is old and was left unfinished until today. Moreover, I can't find any migration referring to the aforementioned table, but for some reason, it thinks the table already exists in the DB. For example, if I change the table name in the Mapping class, like shown below, it will generate a migration with a RenameTable command. And of course, the **update-database** command will fail.

```
this.ToTable("Report");
```

Any idea on how I can solve this?

Comment: Write SQL script with IF EXIST to delete this table (if you don't care about the data) using SQL(",,,") in your migration and then you can add this table again

Comment: @KD Since the table does not exist, I suppose that script won't have any effect? Nonetheless, I tried to add the following line in the generated migration: 

Sql("IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Reports') DROP Table Reports");

And then I generated the migration again, with no effects, as expected. 

Did I miss something on what you said?

Comment: EF is tracking the expected database state with the `__MigrationHistory` table. So lets suppose for a moment that `Report` existed in a previous migration and for whatever reason, someone manually changed the migration `Up` and `Down` code so it doesn't create the table. EF would now still consider the table as available according to its saved migration history and for further migrations it will generate code to change the table instead of creating it. It's all a bit unclear with the provided information.

Comment: I am sure that's the issue. But how can I fix it? What information can I still add to the original post?

Comment: If your code is version-controlled, you may want to find the migration where the change happened and investigate further. A little hack to fix the missing table would be: remove the Entity, create a migration, clear the code from `Up` and `Down` method then apply the migration. Re-Add the Entity and create another migration - should now generate code to add the table.

Comment: A different hack: create the table in sql, as if it was created in the past

Comment: @grek40 I tried finding the migration, and I wasn't able to do so. I also created the table in SQL, and when I generated the migration, it "suggested" so many silly stuff, including deleting related classes, that I decided to follow a different approach. So, I am gonna try your first hack now!

Comment: @grek40 it worked :)  Feel free to answer the question with your first hack, so that I can mark it as the correct answer!

Comment: @grek40 I want to close this question, so please answer it with your solution, so that I can mark it as correct. Otherwise I will do it myself!

Comment: I feel kindof bad writing some guess-hack answer and I don't have too much time at hand. So feel free to write an answer for your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem was fixed by using the following hack:

1. Remove the Entity, and comment out all the locations where it was being used.
2. Create a migration and clear the code from Up and Down methods.
3. Apply the migration.
4. Re-Add the Entity.
5. Create another migration. It should now generate code to add the table.